# He has a sense of grandeur about <him> <himself>

Tags: difference, reflexive-pronouns

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/grandeur):
**(1)** *He has a sense of grandeur about **him***. — I can't understand why (1) is correct.
my variant:
**(2)** *He has a sense of grandeur about **himself***. — It seems to me (2) is the only correct variant.

Why is (1) correct?
What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 13):

If you look at some of the written instances of...

> *He had a* [*sense of grandeur about him*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sense%20of%20grandeur%20about%20him%22)

...it should be reasonably clear that in most if not all of them, the primary point being made is that *people around him had that perception* (but feasibly the subject himself wasn't even consciously aware of this). On the other hand, if you look at written instances of...

> *He had a* [*sense of grandeur about himself*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sense%20of%20grandeur%20about%20himself%22)

...I think you'll agree that they mostly refer to the subject's own perception of himself, and/or the image he wishes to project.

---

TL;DR: The (far less common) option of using a reflexive pronoun in such contexts puts more focus on *how the **subject** presents **himself***.

The normal non-reflexive pronoun works better for the more common nuance (*how **other people** perceive **him***).

Consequently, it's perfectly possibly to say of something "non-sentient" (such as [Darwin's Theory of Evolution](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2008/feb/15/thereisgrandeurinthisviewoflife)) that there's [*a sense of grandeur about **it***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22sense%20of%20grandeur%20about%20it%22). But you'll probably never encounter [*a sense of grandeur about **itself***.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sense%20of%20grandeur%20about%20itself%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AJOqlzUBJwF8Olra6_GFcINyufyZeNxFVQ%3A1679238948252&ei=JCcXZOOFD4yIgAb8grGoCQ&ved=0ahUKEwjjp4PIpOj9AhUMBMAKHXxBDJUQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22sense%20of%20grandeur%20about%20itself%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAM6BAghEApQzAhYxw5gkBJoAHAAeACAAbECiAH0BZIBBzMuMC4xLjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

Comment: But would "himself" in the original sentence be used by a native speaker in any context? I would probably say either "He tried to evoke/project a sense of grandeur" or "He thought/believed he had a sense of grandeur about him" depending on what we are trying to express.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh yes, a native English speaker *will* use "He had a sense of grandeur about himself".  The sentence " "He thought/believed he had a sense of grandeur about him" refers to someone else.  "He tried to *evoke/project* a sense of grandeur" is about what he *tried to do*, not what he *thought* about himself (for example, pretending to be upper class when he knows he's lower class).

Comment: I think the issue is "about", which has two different meanings in the two lines. Respectively: "around" and "relating to".

Comment: @fectin: That's hardly "the issue". The word "about" has a huge range of possible meanings, which is what ***allows*** the actual issue being queried (the difference between the simple or the reflexive pronoun) without the irrelevant distraction of some other changes to the text. There wouldn't really be grounds for a question at all if OP asked about the difference between ***He gives out** a sense grandeur about **himself*** and ***He is perceived as having** a sense of grandeur about **him***...

Comment: ...but your comment implies OP should easily understand the difference between *He had a sense of grandeur **around him*** and *He had a sense of grandeur **relating to himself.*** Or perhaps that should be ***around himself*** and ***relating to him*** (I've no idea which way round you think those two prepositional elements should go to resolve the ambiguity! :) Or indeed whether you think both versions could still be easily distinguished by which prepositional elements they use, with the ***him / himself*** choice making no difference at all (which *you* may think, but I certainly don't).

Answer (score 0):

An analogue might be valuable, because it has concrete nouns (the *sense of grandeur* is more abstract):

*The mountain had a wreath of cloud about **it**.*

Whereas with a more active verb, we might use the reflexive:

*The mountain drew the clouds close to **itself**.*

---

It's possible that the confusion might be to do with the word "about", which here (and in the question) means "surrounding" - not its other meaning of "relating to" (which tends to attract the reflexive pronoun more often).